# Upload zip file contents to S3

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a zip file to S3. These zip files are uploaded by a user and can range from any file size. My first approach would be using [unzip-to-s3](https://github.com/divshot/node-unzip-to-s3) which is great, but the project is using a very out of date library ([unzip](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip)) that keeps crashing with a "Invalid signature 0x80014" error.

Extracting the zip and uploading it to S3 would also not be a very good idea because the packages could vary in sizes. And extracting the files to disk and then uploading it would be an expensive task. (unzip-to-s3/unzip did a good job of this since they auto drain the memory once a file has been uploaded).

Now my question, how can i upload a zip file via node.js and extract it in S3 without using AWS Lambda?

Comment: unzip-to-s3 is pretty simple, you can try to fork it, update libraries. then cross your fingers and hope that it will work.

Comment: @dpa Yes unzip-to-s3 is simple put unzip is alil bit harder. And it highly depends on that library